# CodeContracts on interfaces doesn't works across different projects in one solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-contracts

I have a solution where one projects contains public interfaces & another - their implementations. Interfaces is decorated with contracts. It turned out during testing that

- if interface implementation is in the same project as the corresponding interface than contracts engine works without any issues
- if interface implementation is in another project as the corresponding interface than contracts engine doesn't work.

What can be done in order to solve this issue?

Sample project is here: http://www62.zippyshare.com/v/58772452/file.html (68 kB)

Platform: MSVS 2012 / CodeContracts 1.5.60813.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled building a Contract Reference Assembly (section 6.5 of the [manual](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf))? That functionality is designed to solve precisely this problem.

Comment: This is the very reason. I have already found it, but thank you for help.